# how stopOnFalse flag works in jquery callbacks?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand the jQuery.Callbacks() method with the stopOnFalse flag:

```
function fn1(value) {
    console.log(value);
    return false;
}

function fn2(value) {
    fn1("fn2 says: " + value);
    return false;
}
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("stopOnFalse");
callbacks.add(fn1);
callbacks.fire("foo");
callbacks.add(fn2);
callbacks.fire("bar");
callbacks.remove(fn2);
callbacks.fire("foobar");
```

---

In my opinion this should output this:

```
/*
output:
foo
fn2 says: bar
foobar
*/
```

But actually this outputs this as of the jQuery docs:

```
/*
output:
foo
bar
foobar
*/
```

Please explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the clarification of the above mentioned statement if we do something like this

```
function fn1( value ) {
  console.log( value );
  return false;
}

function fn2( value ) {
  fn1( "fn2 says: " + value );console.log("called fn2")
  return false;
}

var callbacks = $.Callbacks( "stopOnFalse" );
callbacks.add( fn1 );
callbacks.fire( "foo" );
callbacks.add( fn2 );
callbacks.fire( "bar" );
callbacks.remove( fn2 );
callbacks.fire( "foobar" );
```

the output will be

```
foo 
bar 
foobar
```

as the fn2 never gets called now if we change the code to this

```
function fn1( value ) {
  console.log( value );
  return true;
}

function fn2( value ) {
  fn1( "fn2 says: " + value );
  return false;
}

var callbacks = $.Callbacks( "stopOnFalse" );
callbacks.add( fn1 );
callbacks.fire( "foo" );
callbacks.add( fn2 );
callbacks.fire( "bar" );
callbacks.remove( fn2 );
callbacks.fire( "foobar" );
```

the output will be as you had expected earlier

```
foo 
bar 
fn2 says: bar
foobar
```

because the second time fn2 gets called.hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Because since fn is added first, it is called first and since it returns false rest of the callbacks are ignored - thus fn2 is never called

```
function fn1(value) {
    console.log('fn', value);
    return false;
}

function fn2(value) {
    fn1("fn2", value);
    return false;
}
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("stopOnFalse");
callbacks.add(fn1);
callbacks.fire("foo");
callbacks.add(fn2);
callbacks.fire("bar");
callbacks.remove(fn2);
callbacks.fire("foobar");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NU7j6/)

Comment: but return false is added to fn2 and callbacks has to check this and only return the of stopOnFalse and then only stop it. umm confusing a lot...

Comment: I think as soon as a callback returns false the `stopOnFalse` flag stops the execution of the rest